# Pandas dataframe .to_csv is changing datatype

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift, export-to-csv

I am taking a pandas dataframe, converting it to a CSV file, uploading it to S3, and then copying that S3 file to a Redshift table.

Upon Redshift ingestion, I receive an error indicating that a integer column with a value of `0`, is being read in as `0.0`. I have converted the data type to an integer at the dataframe level before reading it to a CSV file, so I think the error must be when it becomes a CSV file. Opening the actual file, that field throwing the error is still `0` however. Any guesses to how I can preserve that value so the ingestion runs smoothly?

Comment: There is most probably `nan` in your column, therefore integers are interpreted as floats.

Comment: Because `nan` is a float, **not** an integer.

Comment: I was hoping this line would handle that `    partner_df['Friends'] = partner_df['Friends'].round(0).astype('Int64')`. It converts those nan to <NA>, which I believe is pd.NaT. However, perhaps the presence of pd.NaT is causing the issue as well?

Comment: Cool, so I then ran this line `partner_df['Friends'] = partner_df['Friends'].replace(np.NaN, None)` to no avail. That nan type does not get changed to None. What am I missing here? @user17242583

Comment: Try `partner_df['Friends'] = partner_df['Friends'].fillna(None)`

Comment: I receive `ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.`. So then I run `partner_df['Friends'] = partner_df['Friends'].fillna(value=None)`, and receive the same error.